# Can i represent derivative as Lipschitz constant, if a function defined on interval (a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, lipschitz-functions, piecewise-continuity

I am working with some piecewise linear functions and its' intervals defined as $I_j$=($x_j$,$x_{j+1}$].

I want to use the derivatives of sub-functions as Lipschitz constants, but in order to do that, the sub-function must be continuous on [a,b] (according to mean value theorem).

So let's say a linear function is continuous and differentiable on (a,b], can I somehow represent its derivative as Lipschitz constant since it's not continuous on [a,b]?

Comment: You need all difference quotients in $[a,b]$ bounded in order to be Lipschitz continuous in $[a,b].$ For what you are working with, in each of the intervals $(x_j,x_{j+1})$ the derivative needs to be bounded (follows, since the derivatives are constant in each such interval), there needs to be at most finitely many of these intervals (for some authors "piecewise linear" allows for infinitely many "pieces"), and (given that you already have continuity) you need each unilateral limit of the derivatives at the partition points to be finite. I think this will also be sufficient . . .

Comment: In looking back over your question, I might have misunderstood your concern. If the function is linear on $(a,b]$ (or even has a bounded derivative on this set), then the function is Lipschitz continuous on $(a,b].$ Moreover, if the function is NOT continuous on $[a,b],$ then the function is not Lipschitz continuous on $[a,b]$ (since Lipschitz continuity implies continuity, and more, namely that a constant function is a modulus of continuity for the function). As far as I understand your question, the mean value theorem is unnecessary, at least in the case of a constant derivative.